# Burning the alcohol after havdallah

Tags: minhag, havdalah

When I was a child, my grandfather, a"h, would specifically use whiskey (usually Slivovitz) for Havdallah. Then he would spill some of it onto a plate and douse the candle into the whiskey and watch the dancing flames burn off the alcohol.

I've seen a few people doing this same things since then. Is this a written minhag? Or is this nothing more than just "fun" for kids (and, perhaps, adults, too?)

Comment: Once I tried it, but since it's flammable I didn't find it that safe. BTW, [slivovitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slivovitz) is not whiskey.

Comment: How much spirit did his cup hold and how much did he drink?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I meant to use "whiskey" generically. I meant any strong alcoholic beverage. But, yes - Slivovitz is (lousy tasting) brandy. It's safe to burn it off if you put the plate in the kitchen sink or something similar.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok A typical "schnapps" glass. Holds about 4 oz., maybe? He didn't drink much of it for Havdallah (that's a separate halachic problem, perhaps.) I can't say if he had more for *Melava Malka*. I was usually asleep by then.

Comment: Schnapps/booze/alcool/liquor doesn't specifically mean whisky, at least according to this Jekke/Tsorfasi

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt You Yekke's are very precise ;-) Fine, you are correct in that whiskey is a distilled alcoholic beverage made from rye or barley malt and bourbon, a subset of whiskey is from mainly corn mash. Inevitably, the machers in my shul educated me a bit in this area and have me try single malts. Slivovitz would be considered like soda to them.

Answer (score 3):

The idea isn't to 'burn the alcohol', but to extinguish the flame in the wine (or whatever was used for the *kos* of Havdala).

> גם נוהגין לשפוך על השלחן מן יין הנשאר בכוס אחר שתיית המבדיל
>   ומכבין בו הנר כדי שיהא נראה לכל שלא הודלק נר זה אלא למצוה לנר של הבדלה
>   לברך עליו ([שו״ע הרב, רצו:ה](https://he.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3434805) בשם הלבוש)

We extinguish the candle in the spilt wine (one should allow the wine to overflow when pouring the Kos, as a *siman bracha*), to show that the candle was lit specifically for the *mitzvah*.